# Maze solver gets stuck in a loop (Stack overflow error)

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, maze

My recursive solver gets stuck at a dead end and can't turn around, causing a stack overflow error. Where am I going wrong?

`solI` is a public array. `x2` and `y2` are public solution coordinates.

```
0-wall
1-open path
2-tried
3-solution
```

**RECURSIVE SOLVER**

```
public static boolean traverse(int x1, int y1) {
    boolean done = false;
    count++;
    if ((count < 100) && (x1 >= 0) && (x1 < solI.length) && (y1 >= 0) && (y1 < solI.length) && (solI[x1][y1] == 1)) {
        solI[x1][x1] = 2;
        if ((x1 == x2) && (y1 == y2)) {
            done = true;
        } else {
            if (!done) { //up
                done = traverse(x1 - 1, y1);
            }
            if (!done) {//left{
                done = traverse(x1, y1 - 1);
            }
            if (!done) {//down{
                done = traverse(x1 + 1, y1);
            }
            if (!done) {//right
                done = traverse(x1, y1 + 1);
            }
        }
        if (done) solI[x1][y1] = 3;

    }
    return done;
}
```

Comment: The problem with your algorithm is that nothing prevents you from going back at a location already considered.

Comment: @MauricePerry the last condition of the if statement checks that the specific block value is 1 (2 is previously concidered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in line 5 of your code. This `solI[x1][x1] = 2;` should be changed to this `solI[x1][y1] = 2;`. Also forget about the `count`. Having `max count = 100` would cause problem in matrices with dimensions more than `10 * 10`.